# Trying to find the pdf of a continuous random variable Y when $Y=X^2$ and $f_X(x)=3/2x^2$

Tags: calculus, probability

I have that $X$ is a random variable with $f(x)= \frac{3}{2}x^2$ when $x \in [-1,1]$ and $0$ otherwise, and that $Y=X^2$. I am trying to find the pdf of $Y$, and my, work so far is as follows:

$F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(x^2 \leq y) = P(x \leq \sqrt{y}) = F_X(\sqrt(y))$

and

$F_X(\sqrt{y}) = \int_{-1}^{\sqrt{y}} \frac{3}{2}t^2 dt = \frac{1}{2}t^3 \big|_{-1}^{\sqrt{y}} = \frac{y^{\frac{3}{2}}+1}{2}$ for $0 \leq y \leq 1$.

By taking the derivative of $F_Y(y)$, I then arrive at $f_Y(y) = \frac{3\sqrt{y}}{4}$, for $0 \leq y \leq 1$.

I am confused because $\int_0^1 \frac{3\sqrt{y}}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$, when it should equal $1$.  Have I made an just some error in calculation or is my understanding wrong elsewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: you forgot the case of $x \geq - \sqrt{y}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(\color{red}X^2 \leq y) = F_X(\sqrt{y})\color{red}{-F_X(-\sqrt{y})}$$

Answer (score 1):

No, recall that there is a positive and negative square root of any positive real, and that the support for $X$ is over $[-1;1]$.   So when $X^2$ is less than a $y$ in $[0;1]$, we find $X$ between the two roots of $y$.

$$\mathsf P(X^2\leq y)=\mathsf P(-\surd y\leq X\leq\surd y)$$